# Dropdown menu to show after login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Alright, so I want to have a dropdown menu to hide before they login and I want the dropdown menu to show after login.
Here is the html code, but I do not know how I can do this with a function.

Help is much appreciated.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<div>
<li class="login" style="display: none;">
<a href="longsteamloginlinknothingimportant">
    <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_small.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <img height="15" img src="" alt="profile-avatar">
      <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account Settings <span class="badge badge-danger"> COMING SOON </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> Jackpot Stats<span class="badge badge-danger"> COMING SOON </span></a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Account Balance</li>
          <li><a href="/skins/deposit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Deposit <span class="badge badge-danger"> COMING SOON </span></a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">History</li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="php/SteamAuthentication/steamauth/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </div>
 </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show some HTML conditionally using PHP, you can wrap it in a PHP conditional clause, like so:

```
<?php if (isLoggedIn()) { ?>
<!-- Your dropdown menu HTML here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Alternatively, and this is probably a better long-term option if you're building something non-trivial, you can use a template engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to render your HTML. In Twig, your HTML might look like this instead:

```
{% if isLoggedIn %}
<!-- Your dropdown menu HTML here -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple , after successful login create a session. And make a condition of session. Example

```
if(isset($_SESSION['anyname']))
{
  // put all dropdown code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS, set the dropdown menu to be "visible" once the login value is true. Initially setting it to false.